# Is it possible to do static import on whole class by single declaration in Java?

Tags: java, methods, import, static, prefix

Can in java declare?

```
   (1) import static com.example.core.MyClass;
```

[image]

where:

```
public MyClass{
   public static double divide(){
      .....
   }
   public static double add(){
      .....
   }
}
```

and in the class where use static import to use freely:
**devide** and **add** methods without the **prefix** - name of the class.
From what I read we can do:

```
 import static com.example.core.MyClass.divide;
 import static com.example.core.MyClass.add;
```

But Can we do it in one statement as I mentioned in (1)

Comment: Yes.. But please note that what you are doing (static import) is not a good programming practice .

Comment: I saw in enterprise software a class only with static constants - 30 or more and when using it in another class ,when use 4-5 of them, using static import to improve readability(my opinion). My case on top is not the best case, I know. Now just ask for learning purposes how I can do this.

Comment: you could use Maro Bolis's method.. But beware - Please don’t use this feature, because over a period you may not understand which static method or static attribute belongs to which class inside the java program. The program may become unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use

```
import static com.example.core.MyClass.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import static com.example.core.MyClass.*;`

`MyClass.*` will load all the properties inside the MyClass you won't need to access properties as MyClass.divide....

Comment: Eclipse give me an error:
Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token, when I use  import static com.example.core.MyClass.;

Comment: @Xelian - use import static com.example.core.MyClass.* ;